# How to use a for loop with a firebase snapshot using NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to replicate the .forEach() method using a normal for loop. The reason is that I need to anidate multiple loops, and the .forEach() method is not giving the expected result.

For exmple, if I want to retrieve my user collection, and for each user retrieve their posts, and for each post retrieve its coments (three diferent collections, with three loops anidated) then concatenate coments for each post, and send an email to each user with their posts+comments. For this I did something like:

```html
const users = await usersRef.get().then(users => {
  users.forEach(user => {  
      const userDocRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.id);
        postsRef.where('user', '==', userDocRef).get().then(posts => {
        posts.forEach(user => { 
        
        ...
```

If I use a forEach(), it gives unexpected results, I think because the exection is not linear.

Instead I want to use a for loop. But I dont know how to iterate through the snapshot:

```html
const users = await usersRef.get();  
  for(let user of users.getChildren()) { 

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `posts` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) that has a `docs` property that is an array of all the documents in this QuerySnapshot. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
for (const post of posts.docs) {
   console.log(post.data())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And then where I used "user.id or post.id" to get the document reference like: const userDocRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(user.id);
I should use post.id or post.data().id    ?
const userDocRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(post.data().id);

Comment: @IteraConsultoríaPYMES you should use `post.id`. `post.data().id` will be looking for a field "id" in the document.